# Rich Text in XPM 2013 SP1

Tags: experience-manager, 2013

I'm having some issues with Rich Text fields in XPM. When I add markup with html tags like `<p>`   or `div` XPM seems to get confused. When I click on rich text field with those tags in it XPM treats it like an empty field and adds a new box with `<add text>` or populates it with a copy of content in it and moves the existing content down. This is not a multi-value field. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Here is my markup and some screenshots:

```
<p>            
  <span>
  <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:Content[1]"} -->
    <p>Generic Item Content <a href="/showcase/LinkTest.jsp"  title="Copy of Generic Item" >Generic Item</a></p>
    <p>asdasdasdasd</p>
    <p style="margin-left: 40px; text-align: center;">asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasd</p>
    <p>asdasdasdasd</p>
    <p>asdasdasd</p>
  </span>            
</p>
```

[image: XPM Issue 3]
[image: XPM Issue 1]
[image: XPM Issue 2]

Comment: Can you check if this is consistent across browsers or just with Chrome? It could be due to html rules (p and div are not valid within a span, so you may want to explore using a different tag - this is a parameter in the Enable Inline Editing TBB)

Comment: I tested it in IE and Chrome and it was happening. Switching to div corrected it. I should have thought of that. Post it as an answer so I can mark you correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It probably is because of html validation in your browser. `<span>` cannot contain block elements, like `<div>` or `<p>`, and changing the element used by Experience Manager in the "Enable Inline Editing" Template Building Block should solve this (you can use a div for instance).